# Htaccess and PHP Direction or routing

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-routing

The URL I want to achieve: `https://example.com/VdnbzeHfua/ep1_mp4`

Note : My page (`index.php`) is located in root folder

when I access this URL `https://example.com/VdnbzeHfua/ep1_mp4` it should not look forward for sub folders

i will get and use the values in the URL with PHP (`index.php` in root folder) like this

```
<?php

$url      = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
................
........... 
?>
```

How to achieve this with php and `.htaccess`?

Please anyone help me solving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You require a standard front-controller pattern, which can be achieved with a  single directive in `.htaccess`:

```
FallbackResource /index.php
```

Any request that would otherwise trigger a 404 is passed to `/index.php` instead.

An alternative method (which is perhaps more commonly seen) is to use mod_rewrite instead. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Although this alone doesn't do anything more than the `FallbackResource` directive does above.

Both methods would require the `DirectoryIndex` to be set correctly, if not already (this will usually be set to `index.php` in the server config). For example, at the top of your `.htaccess`, before the existing directives:

```
DirectoryIndex /index.php
```

You seem to already have the PHP part resolved. ie. check the value of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in order to examine the requested URL, which incidentally will also contain the query string.

You can then include the necessary PHP files as required. For example, this could be something simple like:

```
if ($url == '/about') {
    include('content/about.php');
}
```

But can be made as complex as you like. Obviously an `if` construct won't scale to 1000s of pages.

Comment: @AndroidCse What do you mean? Yes it does.... You already have `$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`. You then parse the `$url` and decide what you want to do, eg. `if ($url == '/about') include('content/about.php');` Obviously you can make this part as complex as you like.

Comment: It Works flawlessly. Thank you.  I just add this `FallbackResource /index.php` to my .htaccess file